# How do we maintain consistent read promise to clients when using a fallback queue?

Tags: exception, architecture, amazon-dynamodb, event-sourcing, eventual-consistency

In my company, we are using Event Sourcing pattern to implement a storage for all changes to the price of a booking. Across the company, different services might try to append events to a booking identified by a booking code.

We use DynamoDB to store the event and it does support consistent read. The thing is in the case when a booking is initially made and the very 1st event is created for a booking code, if we fail to save into DynamoDB for whatever reasons, we put the event into a fallback queue and simply return a success to the client to acknowledge that we already received the event. Client can then move on with their business logic flow and in turn, show a success message to end users. The goal is to not block booking creation at all costs.

The problem is, for a very short period of time, when the event is still in the fallback queue, if clients try to fetch the event using the booking code, they will get back an error although we told them that the write on the 1st event was a success earlier. In a way, we're breaking the consistent read promise here.

I'm trying to find a way where we can improve the design and keep this promise while remaining out of the way of the main booking flow (i.e. not blocking the booking on failure).

I'd be very grateful if someone could throw me an idea to look into.

Answer (score 1):

One solution might be to have the fallback queue be durable (i.e. reading from it doesn't remove elements from the queue) up to some retention period (broadly: the maximum allowable time between initial booking and persisting the creation event to DynamoDB) and instead of being a fallback queue be the actual source of truth for which bookings have been created.

Services can then consume this queue: one of these services is responsible for writing the initial creation event to DynamoDB (which is longer-lived than the queue).  If that service is falling behind and approaching the retention limit, that's an operational emergency, but you're buying yourself time.  Another of these services maintains an in-memory view based on the queue of created bookings which haven't yet made it to Dynamo.